# Which ODE Solution Method to Use?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It has been awhile since I've taken a course in differential equations, and I have problem, which requires I solve an ODE (after transforming a PDE) of the following structure:

$$
f(x) - (x + c_1)f'(x) = c_2xf''(x)
$$

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are nonzero constants.

I'm not looking for the actual solution, I'm looking for the name of the solution method/procedure so that I can look into how to solve these types of ODEs.  Any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: It's called a "variable-coefficient linear second order homogeneous differential equation", try looking up "second order linear differential equation" or something like that. Series solutions or closed-form solutions can be available for these.

Comment: kudos for the desire to learn! Would +5 if I could.

Comment: Is $x = 0$ in the domain of interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More commonly your equation would be written with the coefficient of the highest derivative normalized to 1, which makes it looks like

$$ f''(x) + \left( c_3 + \frac{c_4}{x}\right) f'(x) + \frac{c_5}x f(x) = 0 $$

with singular coefficients on the lower order terms. Hence they are sufficiently [regular](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Regular_singular_point#Fuchsian_condition) to be regarded as [Fuchsian ODEs](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fuchsian_equation). So I would suggest you look into the literature for Fuchsian equations, and for "ordinary differential equations in complex domain".

---

Ah, it being second order and homogeneous helps also. It turns out the general class of "second order linear homogeneous ordinary differential equations with rational function coefficients that admits 'closed form solutions'" can be [solved algorithmically](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=839134).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response!